# escape one variable but not the other in awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, centos

I'm facing a problem with awk in Linux. I would like to do make this script work :

```
awk -v var="$MYVAR" "{gsub(/export OTHER_VAR=\$OTHER_VAR:/, "var")}1" /etc/myfile
```

The problem here is that I want the variable "var" to be interpreted (it works) and the variable $OTHERVAR not to be interpreted, and this I what I can't manage to do.

In the end, I want to do this:

I have a variable

```
MYVAR=export OTHER_VAR=\$OTHER_VAR:some_text
```

I want to replace, in /etc/myfile, the following pattern :

`export OTHER_VAR=$OTHER_VAR:/folder/bin` by `export OTHER_VAR=$OTHER_VAR:some_text:/folder/bin`.

I hope I made myself clear ...

Thanks in advance !

Sylvain

Comment: Why are you using double quotes around your awk code at all? That lets the shell do replacements inside it, but if you're doing it right, only awk variables (like the one you created with `-v`) should be referenced inside awk code.

Comment: Also, MYVAR=export OTHER_VAR=\$OTHER_VAR:some_text` isn't actually a valid shell assignment. Maybe you mean `MYVAR='export OTHER_VAR=$OTHER_VAR:some_text'`? (You don't need the literal backslash inside single quotes).

Comment: Please try to make your code a [mcve], so someone else can run it and not get errors unrelated to your question.

Comment: That said, *personally*, if I had your problem, I'd be using `gsub_literal` from [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just added [$] as RavinderSingh13 said and it worked

Comment: Err, I think that was me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test_document='export OTHER_VAR=$OTHER_VAR:whatever'

search_regex='^export OTHER_VAR=[$]OTHER_VAR:'
replace_str='export OTHER_VAR=$OTHER_VAR:some_text:'

awk -v search_regex="$search_regex" \
    -v replace_str="$replace_str" \
'{gsub(search_regex, replace_str)} {print}' <<<"$test_document"
```

...properly emits as output:

```
export OTHER_VAR=$OTHER_VAR:some_text:whatever
```

Note some changes:

- We're escaping the `$` in the regex as `[$]`. Unlike `\$`, this is parsed consistently across all quoting contexts: It is *explicitly* generating a regex character class, rather than having any other potential meaning.
- Using single quotes for literal strings ensures that no shell interpolation takes place within them.
- Using `{print}` is a bit easier for readers to understand than a bare `1` in `awk`.
- Excluding variable names with meaning to the OS or shell, use of lower-case characters in variable names is in line with POSIX-specified convention. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Comment: Thank you ! The [$] saved my life ;)